# Returning model in Ember

Tags: ember.js

Until now I've always returned a object from Ember route's model hook:

```
model: function(params) {
    var data = {};

    $.ajax({...}).then(function(res) {
        data.first = res.first
    });

    $.ajax({...}).then(function(res) {
       data.second = res.second
    });

    return data;
}
```

I used something like the above every time I needed to load the model in more than one step (like when I need to load two or more models in the same route)

now, with ember-cli (before I was using yeoman, don't know if this matters) trying to return a object as model, I get an error:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {

        var data = {};

        data.one = ['example1'];
        data.two = ['example2'];
        return data;
    }
});
```

The error:

```
Error while processing route: index Assertion Failed: ArrayProxy expects an Array or Ember.ArrayProxy, but you passed object
```

Can anyone say why I am getting this error?

Comment: Did you make any other changes, such as to the controller?

Comment: No, the controller is empty; this is just the first try with ember-cli; I just have the application template and this is the application route

Comment: Is it possible that the default controller is extended from ArrayController? Try putting in a dummy one extended from ObjectController.

Comment: Yes, you are a damn genius!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default controller is extended from `ArrayController`. Try defining your own extended from `ObjectController`.